# SELECT statement in WHERE clause on BigQuery not working

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run the following query on Google BigQuery:

```
SELECT SUM(var1) AS Revenue
FROM [table1]
WHERE timeStamp = (SELECT MAX(timeStamp) FROM [table1])
```

I'm getting the following error:

Error: Encountered "" at line 3, column 19. Was expecting one of:

Is this not supported in BigQuery? If so, would there be an elegant alternative?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Try `SELECT SUM(var1) AS Revenue FROM [table1] t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table1] tt WHERE tt.timeStamp > t.timeStamp)`

Comment: It returns the following: Error: error at: 2.97 - 2.221. Only one query can be executed at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subselect in a comparison predicate is not supported, but you can use IN.

```
SELECT SUM(var1) AS Revenue
FROM [table1]
WHERE timeStamp IN (SELECT MAX(timeStamp) FROM [table1])
```

Comment: Good to know and thanks for the alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Rank() to get the max timestamp, and filter the #1s in the where clause.

```
select SUM(var1) AS Revenue
From
(SELECT var1 
,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as RNK
FROM [table1]
)
where RNK=1
```

I don't know how it works with BQ, but in other DB technologies it would be more efficient as it involves only single table scan rather than 2.